# Is it possible to restart azure queue (servicebus)?

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues

Today I experience that azure queue isn't working. Is it possible to restart it?

Comment: You're going to have to get a lot more specific on what exactly isn't working.  Are you getting an exception?  Is there a problem pushing to the queue or reading off the queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable/disable the Service Bus Queue by using [Update Queue Rest API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj839742.aspx)

Here you need to change the Status of the queue.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

KK